# Using a list of words to search for one of those words in an inputted string

Tags: python

I am trying to use a variable in python such as `words` to store a list of strings that can be used in an if statement in order to search for one of the words in a string.

example code:

```
Input_string = input("Enter a word:")

words = ['cat', 'dog', 'car', 'bat']

if words in Input_string:
    print('Specified word detected')

else:
    print('No specified words were found')
```

I've tried test this but it just returns an error message:
if words in Input_string:
TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By `if words in Input_string`, you are telling python to check `if` the words list is in the string. This raises the error.

So you can do

```
if Input_string in words:
    print('Specified word detected')
```

If you want to check if any of the words are there in the list:

```
Input_string = input("Enter a word:")
Input_string=Input_string.split()
if any(word in words for word in Input_string):
    ....
```

The `any()` function returns True if any item in an iterable are true, otherwise it returns False.

If the iterable object is empty, the `any()` function will return False.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `any`:

```
if any(word in words for word in Input_string.split()):
```

Comment: I'm reading between the lines.  I assumed he expected to enter a sentence ("the cat is blue") and wanted to find for any of the magic words in there, but that's not what the text says.  My guess is he'll be back.

Comment: @TimRoberts That's true, edited my answer

Comment: Your original answer was right, given the original question.  However, your new answer is exactly the code I was going to post!

Comment: @TimRoberts Ouch sorry about that haha!

Answer (score 0):

```
Input_string = input("Enter a word:")
words = {'cat', 'dog', 'car', 'bat'}

found = words.intersection(Input_string.split())
if found:
    print(f'Specified word detected:{found}')
else:
    print('No specified words were found')
```

Prints:

```
Enter a word:the cat and the dog were walking here
Specified word detected:{'dog', 'cat'}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, a question whether "cat" should match when the input string contains "cats" or "catalogue" or "catholic dogma".

Assuming the answer is no, you'd process the input string into words, perhaps stripping punctuation and making everything lower case; then you'd use a set intersection to see if there's an overlap with `words`.

Something like:

```
input_string = input("Enter a word:")
input_words = set(input_string.lower().split()) 

words = {'cat', 'dog', 'car', 'bat'}

if words & input_words:
    print('Specified word detected')
else:
    print('No specified words were found')
```

You could even calculate which particular words matched:

```
overlap = words & input_words
print(overlap)
```